# Make a popup link to content article in php

Tags: virtuemart

I want to have a INFO button on my cart template wich shows a popup whith the content of a article.
In the article is more information about ordering products.
So no images just plain text.

I found out that it can be done with MODAL.
But this
{modal url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W0FOZ0-VpcU}{/modal}
in the php won't work.

How can I do this?

Joomla 2.5.11 an Virtuemart 2.0.20b